# How to get the coordinates for a particular area or region in html5 canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I created a circle using canvas and divided it into lines. I want the coordinate of a particular area: if I click a particular area, that alone should be clickable.

Take an example of a word wheel game where a circle is divided into many areas with different 
coordinates and some letters placed inside the divided areas. If I want to click the particular area with the letter 'A', the 'A' should be clicked and should be displayed in a text box.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: thanks for the correction michael

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following gets you started.

Note that " the particular area with the letter 'A' " is called a sector of the circle.

*Assume*

the x axis is horizontal and positive to the right

the y axis is vertical and positive downwards

angles are measured in radians clockwise from the positive x axis

the first sector starts at angle A

centre of circle is at (cx,cy) and has radius r

the circle is divided into n equal sectors

the cursor is at the position (x,y)

the predefined function Math.atan2(y,x) returns the angle (from -pi and pi) between the positive x axis and the line segment from (0,0) to (x,y)
where i is and integer and i<= x < i+1 the predefined function Math.floor(x) returns i

*Then*

Let S be the angle at the centre for each sector

S=2*pi/n

Create a function getangle(x,y,cx,cy) which returns the angle from 0 and 2pi between the horizontal line through (cx,cy) in the positive x direction and the line segement from (cx,cy) to (x,y)

**Pseudocode**

```
function getangle(x,y,cx,cy)
{
    var ang =  Math.atan2(y-cy,x-cx)   
    if(ang<0)
    {
        ang+=2*Math.PI
    }
    return ang
}
```

Now you can create a function to check which sector, if any, the cursor lies in.

Return -1 if cursor is outside the circle, sector number from 1 to n otherwise.

**Pseudocode**

```
function isInSector(x,y)   (x,y) coordinates of cursor
{
    // first check if cursor is outside of circle
    if((cx-x)*(cx-x)+(cy-y)*(cy-y)>r*r)
    {
        return -1
    }
    // find angle for cursor position
    B=getangle(x,y,cx,cy)
    return Math.floor((B-A)/S)+1
}
```